# How to replace string using RE group in python?

Tags: python, regex

I have a problem when using RE module in python:

```
import re
url='http://list.xxx.com/0-20356-1-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-269036.html'
re_rule=re.compile('.+20356\-(\d{1,3})-0-0-0.+')
new_url=re_rule.sub('2 \1')
```

As I wish, the **new_url** would be 'http://list.xxx.com/0-20356-2-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-269036.html', but python returns `new_url=2`.
I know I had make mistakes when using re module. Which mistakes had I make and how to correct them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your example, why even bother using `re`?

```
url = 'http://list.xxx.com/0-20356-1-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-269036.html'
new_url = url.replace('-1-', '-2-')
print(new_url)
```

produces what you're looking for:

```
http://list.xxx.com/0-20356-2-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-269036.html
```

Comment: Because my given code is only an example,actually I'm writing a function ,there are lots of urls to reset,so I tried re .
Your answer has solved my problems,and then ,can you tell me how to achieve using re?

Comment: You could essentially do the same thing with `re.sub`. `re.sub('-1-', '-2-', url)` will produce the same thing as the `url.replace` code above.  There are some extra flags on re.sub that make it more versatile. Have a look at the docs here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub